# Is it possible to put background image and curved corner in a button in xamarin android?

Tags: android, image, button, xamarin.android, rounded-corners

I am trying to input an image in a regular button, however it does not show up. My code looks like this

```
    <Button
    android:text="@string/buttonexit"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonexit"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/wood"/>
```

I also hoped and included `src` instead of `background`, however it still did not work.

```
    <Button
    android:text="@string/buttonexit"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonexit"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/wood"/>
```

Lastly I also tried to make an image button, however once I added an image I cannot adjust the corners anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AppCompatButton` instead of `Button`.

For a Button, the primary color defined in the app theme overrides any custom background that you want to apply to a Button, but it is not the case for the AppCompatButton.

For example:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
android:text="test"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:id="@+id/buttonexit"
android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
android:background="@drawable/bg"/>
```

Besides, you can also use `ImageButton` to achieve this function.

You can add an image by  property `android:src` and adjust the corners with property `android:background` by creating a shape xml file.

You can refer to the following code:

1.create file `button_shape.xml` in folder `drawable`:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <!--background color-->
    <solid android:color="#20a4e5"/>
    <!--radius-->
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <!--Sets the width and color of the border line-->
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#fffff0" />

</shape>
```

2.set it for `android:background` of `ImageButton`

```
 <ImageButton
    android:text="test"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
    android:src="@drawable/grass"/>
```